# Words comprising the 322 most frequent syllables?

Tags: syllables

There is a list of 322 most common syllables which when used can make up the 5000 most frequent words in the english language.
http://www.fldoe.org/core/fileparse.php/7539/urlt/manual.pdf (Page 34-36)

How do I find naming convention was used for these syllables so that I can find words that contain them.

A different list of most common syllables with words to match would also do.

Comment: What do you mean by "naming convention"?  ly is ly.  What role would a naming convention serve here?

Comment: The name for 'ta' is 'ta'.  It doesn't have a naming convention.  It's just what you get if you break up a word that has 'ta' in it.  Like say tammy.  I'm afraid I still don't understand what you're expecting here.

Comment: That is not always the case. 
For example 'ta'. In the word 'table' it the syllables would be 'teh' and 'buhl' but in the word 'data' the syllables would be 'dey' and 'tuh'

Though both contain 'ta' the do not contain the same syllables.

Comment: That's not a syllables issue.  Syllables don't have a conventional spelling.  Words do.

Comment: If you want a list of words and their syllables is there some reason a basic dictionary wouldn't work?

Comment: Of course they do. Different dictionaries have different naming conventions for naming syllables. 

The number of syllables/breaking up remains the same.

Comment: Are you thinking of the pronunciation guides?  Those are hardly conventional names.  Sometimes the same word has multiple pronunciations.  They are faithful to the sounds but that's why they have to use funky letters.

Comment: Isn't a syllable basically that (pronounciation guide)?

Comment: Well no.  The printed and spoken word are practically two different languages. If you spelled words with the letters used in pronunciation guides I wouldn't even be able to read them.  Upside down e's always confused me.

Comment: A syllable is a unit of a sequence of speech sounds. Speech = spoken word. If you do a bit of research you'll find that this is true.

Comment: Right, but you're asking for their naming convention.  The ones in your list come from printed words.  Thus no convention.  Same syllable may be spelled multiple ways.  No.  Know.  Cat. Kat.

Comment: Ok so given the syllable 'ta' then which word would you say it is a part of ? Table or data?

Comment: Given the syllable 'ta' in the form of the letters t and a I would say it's a part of both.  Given it as a sound I might be able to pick one or the other.  But I can't hear you all the way over here.  : )

Comment: Ok then you clearly have a bit of reading to do :)

Comment: I don't see why you think so.  'ta' is meaningless as a sound without a known word to associate it with.  If you said "ta as in table" I'd know what you mean.  But you didn't.  There is no God of syllables that says it can't be "ta as in data".  There might be a pronunciation guide that picked one sound for it.  There might be another guide that went the other way.  If anything, I've read too much since I don't trust any to be the last word on the matter.  But if you pick up a dictionary it should stick with just one meaning from cover to cover.  Outside that dictionary you're on your own.

Comment: What I'm asking for is precisely that! A word to associate the given set of syllables with.

Comment: Right, And given any syllable there is seldom only one word.  Given a whole set of syllables doesn't improve on this.  You're welcome to pick up a dictionary and write your own.  But there won't be anything conventional about it.

Comment: True, but for my purpose I need just one word to associate with each syllable. Which was my question. If you cannot contribute to the answer and are just framing my question in different ways perhaps we should just agree to disagree and end this conversation here so others can give their input.

Comment: @nette suggest looking at: [Week by week phonics & word study](http://www.scholastic.com/teachers/article/collateral_resources/pdf/80/9780545393980.pdf)

Comment: As CandiedOrange says, those "syllables" were clearly taken from *written* words rather than *spoken* words. (For example, #322 <writ> is pronounced differently in *write* as in *written*, but in both cases the <w> is silent.)